# pandas dataframe - return the value in iloc, or return zero if it does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

In using the iloc method for Pandas dataframe, I want to return zero if the value does not exist: (I have a query which it will always return either one row or an empty dataframe. I want the first left value when it exists)

```
import pandas as pd

mydict = {"col1":[1,2], "price":[1000,2000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
query=df[df['price']>3000]

try:
    print(query.iloc[0][0])
except BaseException:
    print(0)

#print result: 0
```

Is there any better way or built-in method for iloc? I am thinking of something similar to the `get` method of Python dictionaries!

Comment: Chain a .fillna(0) to the end of your query or data frame and this will handle nas for you.

Comment: Why don't you use `fillna` to replace missing values with 0?

Comment: `fillna(0)` will never work, this is about what happens when `query` is an empty dataframe. Filling null in an empty dataframe with `0` will have no impact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can be more pythonic replacing your try/except block with:

`print(0 if len(query)==0 else query.iloc[0][0])`

Explanation: len() applied to a pandas Dataframe returns the number of rows.

Update: as suggested in comments, `query.empty` this is more idiomatic and `.iat` is better for scalar lookups, hence:

`print(0 if query.empty else query.iat[0,0])`

Comment: nice! that's what I wanted! a simple `len` would help here! Combining the two answers I would suggest!: `print(query.iat[0,0] if len(query)!=0 else 0`)

Comment: More idiomatic is to use `if not query.empty` instead of `if len(query) == 0`

Answer (score 3):

You can probably use something like

```
next(iter(series, default))
```

For example, using your input

```
In [1]: 
import pandas as pd
mydict = {"col1":[1,2], "price":[1000,2000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
df
Out[1]: 
   col1  price
0     1   1000
1     2   2000
```

and filtering on price > 2000, gives the default value (which we are setting to zero) since df.loc[mask] would be empty

```
In [2]: 
mask = (df['price']>2000)
next(iter(df.loc[mask]['col1']), 0)
Out[2]: 
0
```

The other cases work as expected. For example, filtering on price > 1500,  gives 2

```
In [3]: 
mask = (df['price']>1500)
next(iter(df.loc[mask]['col1']), 0)
Out[3]: 
2
```

and filtering on price > 500 gives 1

```
In [4]: 
mask = (df['price']>500)
next(iter(df.loc[mask]['col1']), 0)
Out[4]: 
1
```

Comment: Extremely clever and concise way of solving this problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's no intrinsically *better* way than `try` / `except`. The rationale for `iloc` is indexing by *integer* positional location.

The behaviour and functionality is consistent with NumPy `np.ndarray`, Python `list` and other indexable objects. There's no direct way to index either the first value of a list *or* return `0` if the list is empty.

A slightly better way is to be explicit and catch `IndexError` only and use `iat` for accessing scalars by integer location. Moreover, you can index by row and column *simultaneously*:

```
try:
    print(query.iat[0, 0])
except IndexError:
    print(0)
```